# Mongoose Schema, Storing an object which may or may not have properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying an API to get results for tv episodes and saving them to my mongodb collection. The code is as follows:

```
let episode = JSON.parse(response);
                        for(let j=0;j<episode.length;j++){
                          let newEpisode = {
                            title: episode[j].name,
                            number: episode[j].number,
                            season: episode[j].season,
                            date: episode[j].airdate,
                            duration: episode[j].runtime,
                            poster: episode[j].image.medium,
                            description: episode[j].summary
                          }

                          show.episodes.unshift(newEpisode);
                        }
                        show.save()
```

The problem is with the poster variable. The API either returns an object with two strings:

```
poster:
   medium: 'url-to-image'
   original: 'url-to-image'
```

or it returns poster with the value of null.

Is there a way to save poster in the collection so that it saves either both strings if they are present, or null if they are not?
It won't let me cast it to an array, and if I try to save one of the properties like in the above code, I get the error 'cannot read property 'medium' of null'.

Comment: try `poster: episode[j].image.medium || episode[j].image.original,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your object Schema / Mongoose model, define your poster as an Array & do the same in the portion of code highlighted in your post where :

```
 poster: [
     episode[j].medium,
     episode[j].original
    ]
```

Maybe try removing 'image' from `poster: episode[j].image.medium` ?

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. =) If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.